# Meaning of "insofern ... als"

Tags: adverb, subordinate-clause

> Man tat ihm **insofern** unrecht, **als** er noch gar nichts davon wusste.

I can't really understand what "insofern ... als" means even though I looked it up in an dictionary. Please translate this sentence literally to English and explain what the "insofern ... als" here is all about.

Comment: It literally means “They did him wrong insofar as / in view of the fact that he didn't know [of it] at that time.” So he did something, and people treated him as though he had known, while in reality he had not, and that was somehow unfair. Makes sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Literally translation:

> People did him insofar wrong, as he still did nothing about know.

More convenient translation:

> One did him wrong insofar as he didn't yet know anything about it.

Which means that only if he had already known about the topic, one would do him right/it would be justified to do him the way it was done. As he did not know yet, one did him wrong. Yet it expresses that there was a likelihood that the circumstances could or should have known about by himself.

The first part of the sentence says, that him was done wrong - regarding specific circumstances. And these circumstances are explained in the second part of the sentence. That means, you can use "insofern" only if you explain the circumstances as well. Without reference it cannot be used. See examples on [dwds](https://www.dwds.de/wb/insofern).

The "als" here is a usual word to introduce the circumstances, yet it is no automatism, e.g.: *Er hat sich immer ehrlich gezeigt, insofern kannst auch du ihm vertrauen.*

Other [translations](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/insofern) in English are

- in this respect
- in that
- to such a degree as
- in view of the fact that